# Black screen monitor issue

Tags: display

I have a dell Laptop and it suddenly shows black screen when it is on. I read some articles and it said to drained the power and I did. After 4 or 5 time it shows mild dell logo and it's on. It is very mild that I can't barely see the screen. What is it I'm facing what should do to rectify it???

Comment: Is there any other information you can provide? There is very little here for anyone to go on. It would help to know what you've tried so far so we don,t suggest it for nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Get it repaired by a professional

Without seeing the laptop it is tricky to diagnose display issues. That said, given that you can see the logo faintly, it sounds as though there is a problem with the backlight (or possibly inverter, depending on the display). It is possible to fix these (though beyond the scope of this answer), but that will depend on your technical acumen.

If your laptop is under warranty take it to Dell, otherwise take it to a laptop / computer / electronic service shop to be repaired.